# InApp Purchase Interface Guidelines

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

guys.

There is some InApp Purchase interface guidelines? I tried to find one without success.

I have doubt like this: after the user hit the buy button, there is some interface restriction to show the communication progress with my server (i.e, download) or every developer can built his own InApp Purchase user interface (i.e, some can use a table view, others a popover) without any restriction*?

*Of course, considering the restrictions that already exist in iOS guidelines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen in the app store, if there are any HIG on InApp purchases - they may be safely ignored, as I've seen all manners of UI - tables, popups, etc.

Comment: I think that too. Asked just to be cautious and don't get the app reject because of that. Thanks!